# Change column height based on the string inside PrimeFaces datatable

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable where for one column, I would like to change the height of the column based on the string to display. Sometimes the string I am getting is very small and sometimes it is very long. So in case of long string, I would like to change the height of the column so that the entire string can be wrapped inside the column.

Below is the declaration of my data table:

```
<p:dataTable var="employee" id="employees_table"
        value="#{employeeDetailsBean.selectedEmployee.details}">

        <p:column headerText="Employee Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{employee.name}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Employee Previous Work History">
            <h:outputText value="#{employee.prevWorkHistory}" />
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to wrap the text within column. `<p:column width="50" headerText="Employee Name" styleClass="wrap">` add CSS `.ui-datatable tbody td.wrap {
    white-space: normal;
}`

Comment: Check this link for more info on primefaces CSS override http://maxyermayank.blogspot.com/2013/03/overriding-primefaces-css.html